# `Cannot convert 'char(*)[50]' to 'char**' for argument '1' to 'void prac(char**)'` when passing a 2D array to a function

Tags: c++, function, char, argument-passing

I wanna pass 2D char array to function.

However, an error comes:

> Cannot convert 'char(*)[50]' to 'char**' for argument '1' to 'void prac(char**)'

How can I fix the code ? Please help me.

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void prac(char **b)
{
        for(int i=0;i<50;i++)
        {
                for(int j=0;j<50;j++)
                {
                        cout << b[i][j] << " ";
                }
                cout << endl;
        }
}

int main()
{
        char a[50][50];
        for(int i=0;i<50;i++)
        { 
                for(int j=0;j<50;j++)
                {
                        cin >> a[i][j];
                }
        }

        prac(a); // error position

        return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The name of a two-dimensional arrays gets converted ("decay") to a pointer to the address of the first row of the array. So use

```
void prac(char b[][50])
```

or

```
void prac(char (*b)[50])
```

instead of

```
void prac(char **b)
```

Your compiler complained because `a` cannot be converted to a `char**`.